# Вообще непонятная ситуация php + mysql

Tags: phpmyadmin, html, php, mysql

Смотрите есть страница генерации таблицы на основе SQL, она идеально работает, но в ней есть такая функция, чтоб можно было выбирать строки СУБД по статусу, на это дело у меня такой обработчик:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['pageid'])){
    $pageid=$_GET['pageid'];
}else{
    $pageid=1;
};    
include("config.php");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM car_ann",$db);
$results=mysql_num_rows($query);
$num=50;
$start = $pageid * $num - $num;
if($results%50==0){
    $pages=$results/50;
}else{
    $pages=($results/50)+1;
};
$status=$_POST['status'];

echo '...';  //вывод заголовка таблицы

if($status=='4'){
    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM car_ann ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start,$num",$db);
    while($result1= mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
        echo '...'.$result1['price'].'...'.$result1['year'].'...'.$result1['status'].'...'.$result1['id'];  //тело таблицы
    };
}
else{
    $query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM car_ann WHERE status='$status' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start,$num",$db);
    while($result1= mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
        echo '...'.$result1['price'].'...'.$result1['year'].'...'.$result1['status'].'...'.$result1['id'];  //тело таблицы
};
}

echo '...';  //закрываем таблицу

echo '<div class="select">
    <strong>Страница:</strong>
    <select id="selectpage" onchange="selectpage()">'
for($for1=1;$for1<$pages+1;$for1++){
    if($for1==$pageid){
        echo '<option selected="" value="'.$for1.'">'.$for1.'</option>';
    }else{
        echo '<option value="'.$for1.'">'.$for1.'</option>';
    };
};
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Так вот этот обработчик выдает мне

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/webaz/public_html/testpanel/makeofstatus.php on line 41
```

Хотя вроде все ок, тому кто сделает, чтоб все ок выводило, дам 50 очков рейтинга в награду.

Comment: Ужас, в этом трудно разобраться :(

Comment: ну пипец теперь, ты хотя бы уважание у впрашивающих поимелбы....

Comment: Номер страницы в `$_GET`, а статус в `$_POST`.

Comment: @KaZaца спасибо

Comment: @KaZaца, а что не так?

Делаем POST-запрос на адрес server.com/?id=1 и все ОКей.

Хотя, если не принципиально откуда пришли параметры, то лучше $_REQUEST использовать - универсальнее получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам один из запросов в результате выполнения mysql_query вернул значение "false", а вы пытаетесь извлечь массив.

Проверьте запросы, а именно значения переменных, которые вы передаете. Если это третий запрос(не стал считать строки), то это переменные $status, $start и $num.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает ошибку в SQL синтаксисе на 41 линии документа. Проверьте эту строку. Лимит всегда пишите в скобках - LIMIT (1,2). Имя поля всегда пишется в апострофах.